# Laravel get unknown file after upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in my administrator of website, i'm implementing upload file, when i design view and define validations and controller this uploader upload unknown file into `upload` directory when i try to use that

result of `dd($request->all());` is:

```
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "9tNfMnakc6viX2qYRYr6abkrJapo1qz7jG88USYf"
  "title" => "hello"
  "type" => "post"
  "images" => "Untitled-1.png"
]
```

validation:

```
return [
    'title' => 'required|string|max:200|unique:contents',
    'images'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png'
];
```

my store function on controller:

```
public function store(RequestContents $request)
{
    $featured_images = $request->file('images');
    $this->uploadImage($featured_images);
    ...
}

public function uploadImage($file)
{
    $year = Carbon::now()->year;
    $imagePath = "/uploads/post_images/{$year}/";
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move(public_path($imagePath, $filename));
}
```

html:

```
<form action="manage_contents" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...

<div class="media-body">
    <input type="file" class="file-styled" name="images">
</div>

...
</form>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? The file upload seems to work fine.

Comment: @Jerodev problem is after upload file, uploaded file is without any file extension and filename is not same of uploaded file

Comment: `move` is actually not an official function to use for uploaded files, so I'm not even sure why this works.

Answer (score 2):

You need also the extension for the filename. What laravel 5 are you using?

```
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName() . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: `$file->getClientOriginalName()` is with file extension

Comment: laravel version is 5.5 `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$file->move(public_path($imagePath, $filename))
```

To

```
$file->move(public_path($imagePath), $filename)
```

as first parameter takes the destination folder name and the second parameter takes the new file name

[API Reference](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_move)

Comment: removing / from start of `"/uploads/post_images/{$year}/";` and change `move` implementation to `$file->move(public_path() . $imagePath, $filename)` resolved my problem